# OO design: generic handling of sub classes that introduce new fields

Tags: java, oop, language-agnostic

This is a design issue I keep running into, so I thought I would finally put it out there and see how people would approach it. The problem is as follows:

I identify a certain class that for the most part describes all instances of objects I will use, both behaviour and data-wise. That's great and works well for basic objects. Then a few other type of object crop up which need the same data and behaviour, but additionally would like to have an extra field here and there, or an extra data structure.

Let's call the class *Something*:

```
public class Something {
    private int id;
    private String fieldA;
    private String fieldB;
    private List<Data> list;

    // Then we have getters, setters, and some base methods
}
```

Sometimes we'll need to use *SomethingElse* and *SomethingDifferent*. They are 90% like *Something* in that the same data and behaviour describes them, however they each additionally have extra fields which need to be used by the rest of the program:

```
public class SomethingElse extends Something {
    private String dataSpecificToSomethingElse;
    // Then we have getters, setters, and some new-data specific methods
}

public class SomethingDifferentextends Something {
    private List<DifferentData> dataSpecificToSomethingDifferent;
    // Then we have getters, setters, and some new-data specific methods
}
```

I would like to come up with a decent way to handle the *Something* family of objects in a generic OO manner, as I would not like to couple the rest of my application on concrete implementation details (because we might need to add *SomethingWacky* later on). I don't want to deal with the subclasses directly as that breaks polymorphism, and will likely include a need to downcast/do a type switch - yuck.

The approaches I can think of to resolve this are as follows:

1. Create an abstract base class that defines all the methods for the *Something* family. Children then only implement the behaviour they are concerned with providing, leaving a NOP/blank override for methods that are not of concern. This enables everything to be treated the same, but introduces interface bloat.
2. Move responsibility to the base class via generic worker methods, following [Tell, Don't Ask](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TellDontAsk). For example this might be things like display(), doWork(), persist(), getStateFromDisplay(), etc. Each subclass would then take into consideration its data when overriding these base methods. I read an article by Allen Holub recently that suggested something like this might be a good practice. This seems to be moving way too much responsibility for external concerns to the class.
3. Create some sort of a data class that groups all of the extra data/behaviour from subclasses, and refer to that in *Something*. This doesn't feel very OO-like.

I've used approach 1 during a previous project - but in that instance even though each subclass only implemented/overrode the methods it cared about, the operations were actually generic enough so it was plausible that a class could coherently implement all or only some.

Each approach feels dirty in a way and I don't really like any. What are my alternatives? Perhaps I am totally misusing inheritance or approaching this the wrong way entirely. I'm open to any suggestions and would like to leverage OO techniques to come up with cleaner, decoupled designs. I'd really like to know how people have resolved issues like this, and any resources you could refer me to would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Re #2: if your class is persisting itself, aren't you violating Single Responsibility?  

I'd need to know more about the context, but it seems to me you're over-using inheritance -- if you really need to do different things with `SomethingElse`, should it really be a subclass?

Comment: It's not persisting itself. I was just trying to list example behaviours that would move external concerns within the class, and would violate SRP as you say. The subclasses don't really do anything different, they just have additional information to look after..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the need to add `SomethingElse`, `SomethingDifferent`, etc. crops up, I'd ask: Does `SomethingElse` really need to be able to individually access all data and behavior elements of `Something`? Or is its use of `Something` limited to a few methods?

If it's the latter, it's usually a good idea to encapsulate the specific behavior of `Something` that is frequently used by other classes, and then [use composition rather than inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I try to use composition where a class is partially useful, here though the child classes literally are the same as the base - the only difference is that additional data (fields) is needed as an extra for the children..

Comment: It's hard to say without a concrete example, but if 3 classes are 90% the same, then that 90% may be a good candidate for separating out to a different class.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting questions and have to admit that I do come across the same problem often too.

All you said that were all valid and the idea of subclassing is really to address problems that you just describe. Using of ABC is a good OO principle so I suggest that you look into that a bit more. However, in term of defining all the methods interface in the base class - you will need to reassess that. First I think you should take a step back and ask basic OO question about whether or not does all those behaviors apply the the object of that type? I also think that based on the volatility of your domain model, you will know all the possible behaviors upfront/right now or otherwise you probably don't have the problem you just described.

I think you can use the above approach to refactor your inheritance tree and in combination with Decorator design pattern to decouple your implementation and introduce stability to your inheritance tree and allow extensions through the decorator classes.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by using ABC is a good OO principle?

Comment: ABC = Abstract Base Class. Base class should always be abstract for various reasons such as decoupling between implementation and model, as well as base class is often a partial representation of the real world model and we shall not allow abject to be created for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a set of *interfaces* that describe the different *usage scenarios* that come up in your application. The [interface segregation principle and the single responsibility principle](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) come to mind. I think a better way to achieve *code reuse* is to keep your classes as small and focused as possible and to use composition rather than inheritance to delegate some of those interface implementations.